# Why is there a small difference between addresses derived by the cardano-address tool and Yoroi?

Tags: yoroi, address, cardano-address

Let's consider a Yoroi test wallet with the following seed phrase:
`maximum vacuum toe conduct jazz tray romance crawl fossil wisdom disease crazy mountain bird discover`

The first address generated by Yoroi is then:
`addr1q96a42g6ajjhu5gfw8gch2w0vflfxkqw53pxyufgacscal5f0vdmnq834g9upwe2g0cfzwemmwvfnyawg89g8xeqx4kstanhan`

However, if I derive the first address using the [cardano-addresses tool](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) like this (where `phrase.prv` holds the seed phrase):

```
./cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
cat root.xsk | ./cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H | ./cardano-address key public --with-chain-code > root.xvk
cat root.xvk | ./cardano-address key child 0/0 | ./cardano-address  address payment --network-tag mainnet
```

I get the following address: `addr1v96a42g6ajjhu5gfw8gch2w0vflfxkqw53pxyufgacscals656txx`

For direct comparison:
`addr1q96a42g6ajjhu5gfw8gch2w0vflfxkqw53pxyufgacscal5f0vdmnq834g9upwe2g0cfzwemmwvfnyawg89g8xeqx4kstanhan`
`addr1v96a42g6ajjhu5gfw8gch2w0vflfxkqw53pxyufgacscals656txx`

So the first part of the addresses is identical (except for the first letter after the prefix), but there seems to be missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed missing a part of the address: the delegation part. For more information, please refer to this partially [duplicate question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/791/how-to-import-yoroi-seed-phrase-to-computer-using-cardano-address-for-use-with-c) and [CIP-0019](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0019/CIP-0019.md).

To derive Yoroi addresses from a seed phrase using the [cardano-addresses tool](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses):

```
./cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
cat root.xsk | ./cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H | ./cardano-address key public --with-chain-code > root.xvk

# Derive the stake key.
cat root.xvk | ./cardano-address key child 2/0 > stake.xvk

# Only the index of the payment address is incremented to yield the next Yoroi address:

# First address
cat root.xvk | ./cardano-address key child 0/0 | ./cardano-address address payment --network-tag mainnet > payment.addr
./cardano-address address delegation $(cat stake.xvk) < payment.addr > payment-delegated.addr

# Second address
cat root.xvk | ./cardano-address key child 0/1 | ./cardano-address address payment --network-tag mainnet > payment.addr
./cardano-address address delegation $(cat stake.xvk) < payment.addr > payment-delegated.addr

# Third address
cat root.xvk | ./cardano-address key child 0/2 | ./cardano-address address payment --network-tag mainnet > payment.addr
./cardano-address address delegation $(cat stake.xvk) < payment.addr > payment-delegated.addr
```